# Configuring GET Parameters immediately after the hostname

Tags: web, apache2

This is a tough one to explain, but I have a requirement where a file on my web server needs to be accessed as such

http://www.something.com?param=value

I am just using Apache2 hosted on a Linux box and need to access a file on my server from another machine on the same LAN. So technically it'd be something like 
http://ipaddr?param=value

I can't figure how to get this working or how to search for this online. I tried naming my script as "index.php" in the hopes that this might work but even then it needs something like http://ipaddr/index.php?param=value.

What do you call whatever is happening here and is there a way to do it?